# Проблемы с GRUB

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux

В общем интересная проблема: Устанавливал kali Linux на HDD (встроенную) выделил память, после установки все запускалось, GRUB видел обе ОС и спокойно запускал любую из них. На следующий день пытаюсь зайти в GRUB, но он не видит ничего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я понял, что граб просто телепортировался на SSD ( к windows поближе похоже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее чреез GRUB попытался найти вообще что-то, что осталось от всего веселья и последнее, что я выяснил, это то, что Кали на месте, а граб реально на SSD.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С этим что-то можно сделать? Поискав способы в интернете, я максимум вводил команды и ничего не поменялось, старался разобраться и тоже не смог :С

Comment: Если Вы под люнихом ещё ничего не делали, то проще всего - переставить его. Это будет быстрее, чем пытаться понять - в чём проблема. Возможно, на вашем установочном CD или флешке у инсталлятора есть режим "Восстановление Grub" - попробуйте его.

Comment: @Sergey, научитесь, пожалуйста, выговаривать слово Linux (или линукс в русскоговорящем сегменте).

Comment: Я не могу оставить комментарий, так как мало репутации, но хочу помочь Вам в проблеме.
Подскажите, при загрузке `GRUB` вы можете нажать клавишу `е`? должно появиться меню `GNU GRUB`. Если появится, покажите скрин.

Comment: если первым грузится ssd - значит grub там всегда и был